# Knex select hardcoded value as

Tags: knex.js

How do I write following query with knex?

```
select 'Admin' as user_type from table
```

I tried `.select("'Admin' as user_type")` and `.select("Admin as user_type")` and `.select("<tilde>Admin<tilde> as user_type")` but none of these seems to work.

knex.raw works, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```js
knex('table').select(knex.raw("'Admin' as user_type"));
```

Or, for automatic escaping (preventing SQL injections when using user-controlled input):

```js
knex('table').select(knex.raw("? as user_type", ["Admin"]));
```

There is a `knex` [raw](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html) for any custom query you need that is not supported by `knex` default query builder.

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that I have tried raw and it worked. I want it with out knex.raw

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've missed the last sentence of your question. I guess no, there's no other way to select a constant string using knex without raw. I haven't found any by this time.

Answer (score 0):

The below is correct syntax.

```
     knex("table").select("Admin as user_type")
```

If you had already included the table name as I've noted above, try also adding the below clause to your statement to log the SQL code generated and SQL error result at runtime. That should help you more.

```
    .on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
        console.log("KNEX query-error ex:", ex, "obj:", obj);
    })
```

Good Luck!